# jQuery Autocomplete Widget with PHP and HTML Seperate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve a jQuery autocomplete field, however I have my HTML and PHP files separate. I am new to PHP and I don't understand where to put the jQuery code, and how this interacts with the HTML side.

I have index.html (For the HTML)
and I also have index.php (For the PHP)

Here is the text field I would like to be autocomplete:

```
<div class="keywords">
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Keywords" type="text">
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
<!-- jquery Autocomplete -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now what I don't understand is, on this site: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples it has this code as the example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Which at the top shows it in a HTML file. I don't understand how I would keep the PHP and HTML seperate as they are both in different files?

Comment: where is your php code? Php is server based ajax call from html page connects to it using js. But in your example there is no ajax request only array in js, normally this array should be populated by ajax

Comment: `source` at `js` at Question appear to be local , not requested from external source. See "viewsource" at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote , http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

Comment: I have copy and pasted the code above, I am watching video tutorials but I can't get my head around what to do with the PHP. My PHP is in a separate file. I have index.html and index.php